# Burninate "ascending" tag

Tags: support, tags, burninate-request

I've just noticed [ascending](/questions/tagged/ascending). It doesn't have any Wiki entry and I've gone through the 41 questions that have it. All the questions either mention `ascending` in the title, or in the question itself. All questions would have enough context from remaining tags and content, and a couple of questions are actually about `descending` which doesn't have a tag. So, IMHO, I think this tag should go the way of the Dodo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and made the bold decision of untagging the 41 questions that had [ascending](/questions/tagged/ascending). If anyone disagrees, they can downvote this or go through [my edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398242/wesley-murch?tab=activity&sort=revisions) and undo it where necessary (I promise not to make any edits for at least several hours, so they're all at the top), but I think it was a safe move.

Blacklisting the tag might not be a bad idea, but if the number of questions with the [descending](/questions/tagged/descending) tag is any indication, it might not be necessary.

There was *one* question actually *about* the `ascending` keyword that might deserve to use the tag in a legitimate way, but I couldn't see having only one: [Does ascending keyword exist purely for clarity when used with orderby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277106/does-ascending-keyword-exist-purely-for-clarity-when-used-with-orderby)

The tag system is always a bit of a mess, and this one was pretty useless. They say if a tag can't stand on it's own, it's not a very good one. Personally I think there should be some kind of MainTag/SubTag system where minor tags like "ascending" and "left-alignment" can have a place, but that's an idea for another day...

Comment: Thanks. I was on the verge of doing the same but: 1) figured it'd be a good idea for people to offer their opinions and 2) it'd be a lot easier for SE to just run a DB query (or use equiv. tools)... Anyway, good job and thank you very much for your time spent